# Is it possible to make a random string be generated in discord.js? Also to have the backtick formatting

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I was wondering how to make my discord bot generate a random string of letters of numbers  every time a punishment is done, and then include that in the log embed, the dm embed and the confirmation embed. And then the next time, another random one is generated. Also, I want to have the `hi` formatting in js but it's going weird in my VSC I don't know how to do that.

This is what I found for generating a random string:

```js
function getRandomString(length) {
    var randomChars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var result = '';
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += randomChars.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * randomChars.length));
    }
    return result;
}

//usage: getRandomString(20); // pass desired length of random string
```

My code for the Embed is:

```js
  .setDescription(`${verify} ${user} has been **warned** with **ID** `${verify}``)

  var sendEm = await msg.channel.send(warnEmbed);
  msg.delete()
}
```

I try to put backticks in $verify) but it doesn't work because it makes all the code underneath orange, does anyone know how to help for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to [escape the backtick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#description). Escaped characters are treated as any normal character in a string. It's as simple as putting a backslash in front of the character you want to escape.

So in your case, you'd need to do this:

```js
// Using "\`" will insert an actual backtick in the string
.setDescription(`${verify} ${user} has been **warned** with **ID** \`${verify}\``)
```

Comment: I havent tested out that code but from what I can see, you've declared a variable `ID` in the function `makeid` but you're trying to use it outside of that function. To fix this, define the `ID` variable outside the function, and make the `makeid` function return its result. Take a look at this paste bin: https://pastebin.com/rtk10PVK